# R Shiny: show text output for a certain time period

Tags: r, shiny

In my Shiny app I want some text to show in the UI after clicking on an action button and then it should disappear again after some seconds. How can I do this? I tried to use InvalidateLater, Sys.sleep() and ConditionalPanel, but I didn't succeed. 
Below a simple example. It shows the time after clicking. I want the time to disappear after some seconds. If you click again a new time must appear.
How can I do this?

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("btn", "Click to show current time"),
  textOutput("temp_text")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # make text with time stamp after click  
  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    output$temp_text <- renderText({
      paste0("The time is: ", strftime(Sys.time(), format = "%H:%M:%S"))
    })

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Is it ok to show the text in an alert window ? Otherwise, how do you want the text to be displayed ? Your expectations are not clear enough.

Comment: No I want to show the text as an TextOutput. I added an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with the `delay` function of `shinyjs`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  actionButton("btn", "Click to show current time"),
  textOutput("temp_text")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  Time <- reactiveVal()
  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    Time(paste0("The time is: ", strftime(Sys.time(), format = "%H:%M:%S")))
  })

  output$temp_text <- renderText({
    Time()
  })

  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    delay(ms = 2000, Time(NULL))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```